# What is the difference between a server built machine and a home pc

Tags: desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between motherboard/processor for server and the ones for desktop ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100375/what-is-the-difference-between-motherboard-processor-for-server-and-the-ones-for)

I've been hosting stuff on my computers for the last couple of months from my home personal computer.  What is the difference between this and something such as this:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16859105954

Does this have a visual?  (How do I get on it to run stuff on it?)  Can I just start normal .exe's on it?  Do I have to do things differently?  What are the spec comparisons?  What would be better, a $250 server (such as the one above) or a $750 gaming computer?

Are they built differently (for specific things) or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular system is barely above a home PC.

It does have a visual (on-board VGA). You can install whatever x86 OS you want on it.

These are the features that make it somewhat better than your average PC:

- ECC memory
- RAID1
- accepts 4 drives (@ 2TB each for 8 TB total)

You can get PCs with those features. Regular servers are actually much different than home PCs. They usually have these properties (I'll use a HP DL 360 as an example):

- are a standard size that fit into standard racks (1u)
- have more CPUs (2x 6-core)
- have more memory (384G)
- have more NICs (2 dual port with TOE and iSCSI accelerator)
- have more disks (8)
- use higher performant disks (15k RPM SAS)
- have RAID controllers with BBWC
- have hot/swappable drives, power supplies
- have redundant power supplies and fans
- have out-of-band management capabilities (ilo)
- don't care that their noise would make you go deaf
- have poor on-board graphics

Comment: Have a bigger bus, larger CPU cache, and better CPU load balancing, not to mention multi-channel RAM and heftier power-supplies